# How to implement LeafValueEditor<Address>

Tags: gwt

I am trying to understand how to correctly implement a LeafValueEditor for a non immutable object. Which of the two way is correct, or should something else be used?

```
public class Address {
   public String line1;
   public String city;
   public String zip;
}
```

Option 1:

```
public class AddressEditor implements LeafValueEditor<Address>
{

    private String line1;
    private String city;
    private String zip;

    private Address address;
    public void setValue(Address value)
    {
       this.line1 = value.line1;
       this.city = value.city;
       this.zip = value.zip;
       this.address = value;
    }

    public Address getValue()
    {
        this.address.line1 = this.line1;
        this.address.city = this.city;
        this.address.zip = this.zip;
        return this.address;
    }

}
```

Option 2:

```
public class AddressEditor implements LeafValueEditor<Address>
{

    private String line1;
    private String city;
    private String zip;

    public void setValue(Address value)
    {
       this.line1 = value.line1;
       this.city = value.city;
       this.zip = value.zip;
    }

    public Address getValue()
    {
        Address a = new Address();

        this.a.line1 = this.line1;
        this.a.city = this.city;
        this.a.zip = this.zip;

        return a;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably neither, though both technically could work.

A LeafValueEditor is an Editor for leaf values - that is, values that don't generally contain other values. Usually a text or date or number field that would be visible on the page is the leaf editor, and those leaf nodes are contained in a normal Editor.

In this case, it could look something like this:

```
public class AddressEditor extends Composite implements Editor<Address> {
  // not private, fields must be visible for the driver to manipulate them 
  // automatically, could be package-protected, protected, or public
  protected TextBox line1;//automatically maps to getLine1()/setLine1(String)
  protected TextBox city;
  protected TextBox zip;

  public AddressEditor() {
    //TODO build the fields, attach them to some parent, and 
    //     initWidget with them
  }
}
```

See http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html#Editor_contract for more details on how this all comes together automatically with just that little wiring.